# Is this the way to find memory leaks in my ActionScript 3 application?

Tags: actionscript-3, memory-leaks, flashdevelop

I just tested the FlashDevelop profiler with my application. When I keep going back and forth between two menus, the numbers in the "Live Objects Count" tab increase for "Function", "Class" and "Sprite", but not for "Namespace" and "Object". Does this mean that I have a memory leak, or could it be caused by slow garbage collection?

In general, is this the way to find memory leaks? Doing things a couple of times and checking if the memory usage and object count keep rising?

Comment: No it is not. There is no way to know if the GC was triggered. For debug I would force the GC when you switch iterations.  And profile with that in effect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the way to find memory leaks, and yes you have one(at least). Garbage collector is not triggered immediately, but if after few iterations you **totalMemory** and instances count increasing, you've got a problem. As you may know, most typical issue is unsubscribed event handler(s). Try looking into this.